# Access json post data with php

Tags: php, json, post, sendgrid

I am writing a small PHP app that will take the post data from Send Grids Webhook API but it looks like it is sending json as post data. I am not sure how to access that data. I have worked with post data before but I access it using $_POST I have never received json post data.

Here is my code, let me know if I am going in the right direction

```
include 'send_grid_conn.php';
$dealer = (isset($_GET['dealer']) && !empty($_GET['dealer']))?$_GET['dealer']:"N/A";
echo $dealer;

$postData = json_decode($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA,true);

$email = (isset($postData['email']))?$postData['email']:"nothing";

    $stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO `send_grid`(`email`, `dealer`) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->execute(array($email, $dealer));
```

The insert part works but I cant access the POST data.

I'm going to clean up the code btw. Right now I'm just in test mode trying to access that json data.

Comment: Try `var_dump($postData)` to see what the array contains.

Answer (score 0):

`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` is deprecated as of php 5.6 and removed as of php 7, you should use `php://input` as it won't depend on any php.ini configuration, and, did you try decoding `$_POST`?. In the request, json is just a string, so you should not have any issue.

With `php://input`:

```
json_decode(php://input, true);
```

With `$_POST`:

```
json_decode($_POST, true);
```